# Error in storing downloaded images into a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, global-variables

I would like to store all the images I downloaded on my computer to the variable called X_data.

```
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np

X_data = []
for img in glob.glob ("C:\\Users\\User\*.png"):
    image = cv2.imread(img)
    X_data+=[image]
    print('X_data shape:', np.array(X_data).shape)
Output:
X_data shape: (1,)
X_data shape: (2,)
X_data shape: (3,)
X_data shape: (4,)
X_data shape: (5,)
```

However, when I print `X_data`:

```
[None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
....]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
import os
X_data = []
path="c:\\your_path"
files = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if ".png" == x[-4:]]
for myFile in files:
    image = cv2.imread(myFile)
    X_data.append(image)
print('X_data shape:', np.array(X_data).shape)
```

Comment: When I call X_data, the output is [None, None, None...]? for 2000 rows

Answer (score 0):

Your files will take only one image file. You have to run it in a loop to take all the images.

```
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np

X_data = []
for img in glob.glob ("your path\*.png"):
    image = cv2.imread(img)
    X_data.append(image)
print('X_data shape:', np.array(X_data).shape)
```

Comment: I am not sure whether I get it correctly, but when I call "X_data", the output is [ ]?

Comment: How are you getting an empty list.? I get the output as "X_data shape: (3,)"

Comment: Yes, I get the output: X_data shape: (2000,). But if I call `X_data`, the output is [None, None, None]?

Comment: Please let me know how are you calling it?

Comment: input: `X_data` | output: `[None, None, None, None...None]`

Comment: Try this and check if you getting image matrix. As you're having 2000 images we'll try to print 1 image.
for i in X_data[0:1]:
    print(i)

Comment: Output: `None`.

Comment: Are you really appending the images to the list?
try X_data+=[image] in the for loop instead of X_data.append(image).

Comment: Still experience the same problem, I have appended the changes in the question